# Alienware laptop Built in sound card headphone and microphone jack not working

Tags: 14.04, sound, laptop, microphone, alienware

I have an Alienware m17x r4. My speaker's are working just fine.But when i plug my headset in the sound does not come through the headset and still comes through the speakers I have a creative soundblaster recon3di. Could someone explain me to me how to fix it. I'm fairly new to linux

Answer (score 0):

Click the sound icon on the top right and then click on sound settings.

Plug-in your headphones and click the test sound button. Then disconnect and and make sure you don't see speakers instead of headphones like is presented in the screenshot to check if your headphones are being detected.

Comment: Even when it says headphones built-in audio it still comes out of my speakers